# Adding code to a post under a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

So I was asked to add some analytics code to a sponsored post. I usually do it like this:

```
if(is_single('post_slug')):
// Insert analytics code;
endif;
```

However, I cannot figure out how to do it on a post with a custom post type.

I found this function which takes the slug of the custom post type:

is_singular('event');

My question is, is there a function that would take the custom post type and the slug of the post?

Would really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/ "Works for any post type, except attachments and pages"

Comment: Add a custom field to all posts of the specific type. Let them set a checkbox if the post should have analytics. After that check the value and add the analytics.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix two functions:

```
if( is_singular( $post_type ) && is_single( $post_slug ) ):
// Insert analytics code;
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use shortcode!

Put this inside functions.php

```
// Assign the tag for our shortcode and identify the function that will run. 
add_shortcode( 'custom-analytic', 'wpse61170_custom_analytic' );

// Define function 
function wpse61170_custom_analytic() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    //Put your analytics code here
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

In any page you want the analytics to show, just put this shortcode

```
[custom-analytic]
```